# Black actors in "Game of Thrones"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

How many black actors appear in the TV Series *Game of Thrones*?

I know that there is one in Dorne (The guard of Doran Martell - Areo Hotah) and another in Qarth (Xaro Xhoan Daxos).

How many more appear?

EDIT:
I found one more: Salladhor Saan
System Down found: The priest of the Many Faced God (pre-transformation)

Comment: Xaro Xhoan Daxos in Qarth + The guard of Doran Martell

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira Thanks! But how many more? I need to know!

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59521/2256

Comment: To answer this question, you'd have to choose an arbitrary line on which side you put people you consider "black guys" and everyone else on the other. Grey worm has darker skin than Daneries does that make him a black guy?  [Kobarro](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Kovarro)  and a few of the other Dothraki might need inspection too.

Comment: @nuno.filipesf May I ask why you need this info?

Comment: @nuno.filipesf all the characters that are supposed to be from the summer isles are black skinned, that includes salladhor saan and Daxos. So if you want a definite list just check the characters from the summer isles that appear in the series (some of them are removed from the series even though they appeared in the books like the archer Black Balaq). Check this link: http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Summer_Islands

Comment: @MikeyMouse You're right! When i posted the question, i was thinking in the darker skin colours, like Xaro Xhoan Daxos. It's not a racist thing, only curiosity!

Comment: @Boelabaal Why anyone need this kind of info? Because of nothing, of course! Just foolishness! And because of science.

Comment: The priest of the Many Faced God (pre-transformation) is black as well.

Comment: @SystemDown the servants of the many faced god don't have particular faces. We don't know for sure what they really look like

Comment: @yondaime008 - The OP asked about black "actors" not black "characters". So while the priest himself may or may not have been black, his actor was.

Comment: Hang on, how is this "primarily opinion-based"?

Comment: @SystemDown indeed, I misinterpreted OPs question.

Comment: How can this possibly be answered until the series is finished?

Answer (score 20):

You'll have to ask the [Unsullied](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Unsullied)... but be polite about it.

[image]

Comment: **<comments removed>** Please take the discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23739/discussion-on-answer-by-daft-black-actors-in-game-of-thrones).

Answer (score 14):

Major characters so far include:

- [Jacob Anderson (Grey Worm)](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2760664/)
- [Nathalie Emmanuel (Missande)](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2812026/)
- [Nonso Anozie (Xaro Xhoan Daxos)](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1996829/)
- [Lucian Msamati (Salladhor Saan)](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1748634/)
- [Deobia Oparei (Areo Hotah)](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0649046/)

There are also many actors of color represented in:

- Qarth
- Astapoor
- Meereen
- The Unsullied
- The Dothraki Hordes
- The Summer Isles

Comment: If you're looking for a number like "124", then you'll be hard-pressed to determine how many unique extras/unnamed characters there are. If you only want named characters, I recommend IMDB.

Comment: These are episodic characters from season 5:
Cedric Henderson as a Faceless Man, 
Reece Noi as Mossador, 
Marcos James as White Rat, 
Gary Pillai as Merchant Captain