# Which speaking roles on Game of Thrones are played by non-European actors?

Tags: game-of-thrones, actors

It is well known that most of the *Game of Thrones* cast is European. By European, I count people that have at least one nationality being inside Europe in the large meaning (so I don't restrict to EU). Also, I mean to find actors who have a distinctively speaking role in the show. I tried to find them all from Wikipedia, but I could only name three:

- Peter Dinklage (playing Tyrion Lannister)
- Jason Momoa (Khal Drogo)
- Pedro Pascal (Oberynn Martell)

I probably missed some, so who are all the actors in *Game of Thrones* who fulfil the following conditions?

- Must have no European nationality: for instance, if an actor is both English and American, he's considered European; Iceland is not part of the EU, but still part of Europe, so Hafþór Júlíus Björnsson is also considered as European.
- Must have a distinctively speaking role. This question doesn't include actors who do not speak on screen unless the role is named, at least minor and meant to be silent; also people only shouting in unison shouldn't make the list.

Comment: Among the dominant characters, I'm pretty sure that Peter Dinklage, Jason Momoa, and Pedro Pascal are the only non European actors in a heavily british cast. Unless you consider Lena Headey, who was born in Bermuda, which is still a British Overseas Territory

Comment: @yondaime008 I believe that [Lena Headey has the British nationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lena_Headey), so she's considered as European according to my criteria.

Comment: Alexander Siddig is Sudanese / British I think.

Comment: Okay, so it seems this question is bad (two downvotes, no upvote). Can anyone tell me why before I delete it? Because according to the [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), it's still acceptable?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire i didnt downvote, but i think this question is more suitable for http://movies.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Not my DV, but frankly I don't see the point of this. It's trivia knowledge at best.

Comment: Thanks. I don't mind the downvote itself. But I just don't understand how I can grasp how to make better questions by downvotes only. I don't have enough rep, but isn't there a close-vote for "other community" such as the one on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Close Votes are for Questions which are against asking policy. Your Question is not against the Policy (Although I always consider lists to be very close to too-broad). But just because a question is acceptable by established policy does not mean it's a Good question

Comment: I did downvote.  This seems to be similar to other questions that have come up in the past (such as http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89693/black-actors-in-game-of-thrones?rq=1) and just seems trivial.  It's on topic, I just don't think it's a good question.

Comment: also related to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59521/why-are-most-of-the-main-characters-white-english-in-game-of-thrones?noredirect=1&lq=1, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133018/why-does-everyone-in-game-of-thrones-have-a-british-accent?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Questions like this that are about the production process, cast, behind-the-scenes etc of a TV show or film tend to be more positively received at http://movies.stackexchange.com This site tends to be better for in-depth within-the-fictional-world stuff. Both are on topic on both sites, it's just a matter of what the regulars tend to be most interested in. If it was my question, I might ask for it to be migrated to the other site

Comment: I didn't downvote but it seems a pointless question to me. How many of the cast are left-handed? How many speak more than one language? How many are over six feet tall? It seems similar to these other pointless questions.

Comment: I'm not super interested in the question, but it was good enough I came here to read it, and it's well written, so here's an upvote.

Comment: @TheMathemagician the difference between this question and those is, at least one person cares about the answer to this, which is why it's been asked, while no-one cares about the answer to those, which is why they haven't been asked. If you don't care, you can simply not click.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Main Actors

Out of the main actors as listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_of_Thrones_characters), [*Peter Dinklage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Dinklage) (Tyrion) and [*Jason Momoa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Momoa) (Drogo) are both American. *Peter Dinklage* is of European descent, however I've disregarded the fact as that is mostly from European settlers. *Jason Momoa* is of Hawaiian and Native American descent, however his mother is also of German and Irish descent.

#### Some more actors

As noted above, [*Pedro Pascal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_Pascal) (Oberyn Martell) is Chilean. [Keisha Castle-Hughes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keisha_Castle-Hughes) (Obara Sand)<sup>1</sup> is Australian. [*Dar Salim*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dar_Salim) (Qotho) is also Iraqi (Bearing in mind he moved to Denmark as a refugee at age six). [*Alexander Siddig*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Siddig) (Prince Doran Martell) was also born to a Sudanese father (albeit English mother) in Sudan. [Joe Naufahu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Naufahu) (Khal Moro)<sup>2</sup> is from New Zealand, with Samoan, Tongan, Portuguese and German descent.

Note: These were most that I could find. I also found [this](https://m.imgur.com/OLYTooC?r) image everyone in more than 5 episodes supposedly, don't know how authentic it is though.

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to [@DariM](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58883/darim) for pointing that one out!
<sup>2</sup> Thanks to [@Mooz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21267/m%c3%b6oz) for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks! As European, the "descent" are mostly a (North-American) thing. Also, I mentioned "nationality" and I don't see other meaning that the one usually meant.

Comment: The image is wrong on one count at least. The handmaiden shown to be from Nepal is born to a Nepalese Father but she holds Norwegian nationality. I think they got the British, American and Dutch characters absolutely right though.

Comment: Ye, sorry I could only look at it on my phone, and I haven't exactly delved into the World of Ice and Fire enough to be able to know all the characters by sight yet.

Comment: @Jvizzles Keshia Castle-Hughes is a New Zealander who was born in Australia

Comment: @DariM, I just went off of what Wikipedia has as her birth place and looked for any mentions of European Nationality. Guess I missed the New Zealander part.

Comment: [Joe Naufahu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Naufahu) who plays Khal Moro (speaking role) is from New Zealand

Answer (score 2):

Robin Arryn is played by a Brazilian actor (Lino Faccioli).

Comment: Here's his [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lino_Facioli) and [IMBd](http://m.imdb.com/name/nm2996220/bio?ref_=m_mn_ov_bio). From the latter, he *was* born in Brazil but moved to London.

Answer (score 2):

### American

- [Peter Dinklage](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0227759/): Tyrion Lannister
- [Jason Momoa](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0597388/): Khal Drogo
- [Rosabell Laurenti Sellers](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3065809/): Tyene Sand

### Chilean

- [Pedro Pascal](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0050959/): Oberyn Martell

### Australian

- [Keisha Castle-Hughes](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1095720/): Obara Sand
- [Conan Stevens](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1947403/): Gregor Clegane

### Iraqi

- [Dar Salim](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1502469/): Qotho

### Sudanese

- [Alexander Siddig](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0796502/): Doran Martell

### New Zealander

- [Joseph Naufahu](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0622533/): Khal Moro

### Brazilian

- [Lino Facioli](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2996220/): Robin Arryn

### Bermudian

- [Lena Headey](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0372176/): Cersei Lannister

### Nepalese

- [Amrita Acharia](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3822505/): Irri

### Israeli

- [Ania Bukstein](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0119804/): Kinvara